# Custom variables in Application Registry

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to add an custom variable to an ApplicationInfo, so that another install4j Setup could check the value of this variable?

The Use-case is that we want to provide an variable for an Application so that the setup of an Add-on can check this variable for its compatibility.

It's not possible to use the Version to check the compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 6.1, this is not possible. You would have to save a property file in the installation directory and read that file.

Comment: Ok just as i thought.
Thanks for the Answer.